# On form submit open PDF url not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a contact form using Contact form 7, and on form submit I am trying to redirect user to PDF url, it seems to be working in Chrome/Mozilla but not working in Safari (Mac), Following is the code I am using to redirect:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://sitename/fileurl.pdf';
}, false );
```

Can anybody suggest what issue it might be?

Thanks

Comment: Does the `<form>` submit before `location` is set?

Comment: Yes form submit before the `location` is set

Comment: Have you tried calling `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: haven't tried that..but will give a try now

Comment: Is there any information in the error console?

Comment: This is what I see in console, but looks like its not for this.. `Content Security Policy: Directive ‘frame-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘child-src’ instead.`

Comment: What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: Nothing, just the same page showing

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the line where you set the location (or add an alert() if you prefer) and see if the event 'wpcf7mailsent' is triggered (and listened to) correctly.